# Correct way to marshal SIZE_T*?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, intptr

I have the following C++ function definition, which I am trying to call through PInvoke from managed code:

```
bool FooBar(SIZE_T* arg1);
```

My managed declaration looked as follows:

```
[DllImport("mydll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool FooBar(ref uint arg1);
```

Some of you may notice the same bug I eventually did. This is not 64bit portable. SIZE_T is of variable size (32-64 bit) as is the pointer to it. On the managed size the pointer correctly translates to 64bit, but the uint does not, and you can end up with trash in the upper bits of arg1. This was an especially persistent error since the trash was often just zeros :(

The only solution I have gotten to work is the following managed declaration:

```
[DllImport("mydll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool FooBar(ref IntPtr arg1);
```

This works of course because IntPtr can vary its size correctly. In my code I just treat the IntPtr as an integer, and it works, though it looks like an ugly hack. It seems to me there should be some way to specify this properly, perhaps using UnmanagedType.SysUInt, but I have been unable to come up with any other working solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `IntPtr` and/or `UIntPtr` *is* doing it properly - the types are there specifically for this purpose! I do not understand why you consider it an "ugly hack". I'm also not sure what your proposed alternative would be - any kind of attribute to allow values to be mapped to `uint` would be inherently wrong, because C# `uint` is guaranteed to be 32-bit regardless of the architecture, and so on 64-bit platform, to marshal it correctly, it would have to trim half of it, losing data, and likely rendering the result useless.

Comment: I view it as an ugly hack because IntPtr should represent a pointer to something. I am simply treating it directly as an integer however. SysUInt specifically states that it is a variable size representation of a uint. Exactly what I want, except I can't figure out how to corectly marshal it as a SysUInt pointer, rather than a SysUInt.

Comment: You are using a pointer to SIZE_T as an argument, Soonil. IntPtr looks very appropriate

Comment: You'll notice I am not using IntPtr however, I am using ref IntPtr.

Comment: `ref` will always correctly map to pointer on any platform. `IntPtr` will correctly map to `size_t`.

Comment: @Soonil, there is nothing to say that `IntPtr` "should represent a pointer to something". MSDN describes it thus: "The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is platform-specific. That is, an instance of this type is expected to be 32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on 64-bit hardware and operating systems". So, it is simply an integral type that matched the word size of the platform. So is `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` (usually, anyway), so the mapping is perfectly normal.

Comment: On a side note, on MSIL/CLR level (which is the lowest you can get), `int` is known as `int32`, while `IntPtr` is known as `native int`. If it's the "Ptr" prefix of the type in BCL that confuses you, then you shouldn't treat it to mean "integer that is pointer". Rather, it means "integer that is of the same size as pointer".

Comment: Seems like the answers given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589846/why-cant-we-do-intptr-and-uintptr-arithmetic-in-c contradict the idea that "there is nothing to say that IntPtr "should represent a pointer to something". The lack of math operators defined for IntPtr and UIntPtr seem to reinforce this as well.

Comment: What about [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)].... Seems to be the 'recommended' way, but I haven't gotten it to work...

Answer (score 19):

**UIntPtr** is the correct type to use.

size_t is an unsigned, pointer-sized integer and that's exactly what UIntPtr means. The "ptr" in the name can be a bit confusing, I agree. It doesn't actually mean "this is a pointer", it means "this is a *pointer-sized* integer". So your declaration would be:

```
[DllImport("mydll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool FooBar(ref UIntPtr arg1);
```

Comment: Ah very well then :) Wouldn't be the first badly named API, heh.

Comment: Actually, that's kind of a common name for that kind of type. Win32 APIs has typedefs `INT_PTR` and `UINT_PTR`. And ISO C99 has `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` in `<stddef.h>`. So while it may be a misnomer, by now it's a traditional one.