# How to marshal size_t cross-platform, using semantic types

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

According to my understanding, MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SysUInt) is supposed to marshal a platform-specific unsigned integer type (either 32 or 64 bytes) into the managed type (ulong).

```
     /// Return Type: size_t->unsigned int
    ///bgr: uint8_t*
    ///width: int
    ///height: int
    ///stride: int
    ///output: uint8_t**
    [DllImportAttribute("libwebp.dll", EntryPoint = "WebPEncodeLosslessBGR")]
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
    public static extern ulong WebPEncodeLosslessBGR([InAttribute()] IntPtr bgr, int width, int height, int stride, ref IntPtr output);
```

But it doesn't work - I get this error:

```
Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int64/UInt64 must be paired with I8 or U8).
```

I know [I can switch the return type to IntPtr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309509/correct-way-to-marshal-size-t), but that's very un-intuitive on the people using my API.

Why is SysUInt not working?

Comment: `UIntPtr` is surely the right type. Why do you want `ulong`?

Comment: Semantics, it's a public API.

Comment: You can use size_t in a public API

Comment: .Net doesn't have a size_t Type, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep the PInvoke method private with `UIntPtr`, and implement another method with your preferred signature, that call the PInvoke mapping everything correctly, and this one would be public:

```
/// Return Type: size_t->unsigned int
///bgr: uint8_t*
///width: int
///height: int
///stride: int
///output: uint8_t**
public static ulong WebPEncodeLosslessBGR([InAttribute()] IntPtr bgr, int width, int height, int stride, ref IntPtr output)
{
    return (ulong)_WebPEncodeLosslessBGR(bgr, width, height, stride, ref output);
}

[DllImportAttribute("libwebp.dll", EntryPoint = "WebPEncodeLosslessBGR")]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
private static extern UIntPtr _WebPEncodeLosslessBGR([InAttribute()] IntPtr bgr, int width, int height, int stride, ref IntPtr output);
```

When frameworks gets to difficult to deal with... just don't use them. Marshaling is a pain, I tend to just use the things that I already know... everything else, I just go around.

**EDIT**

It is not working because the marshaler is not smart enough to see that every `SysUInt` type fits in a `ulong` type. It is checking the return, the same as arguments.

It is true that you cannot use `ulong` and `SysUInt` for an argument, but you could for the return... it is just not smart to see the difference. =\

**What alternatives are there?**

`UIntPtr` seems to be the best choice... but there are other choices: implement a custom marshaler, using interface [`ICustomMarshaler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler.aspx)... and use `UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler`:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(CustomMarshalerType))]
```

**ICustomMarshaler implementation**

With this implementation of ICustomMarshaler you may be abled to do what you want. I did not test it, since I don't have an unmanaged library to do the test, but it is straight forward, and very simple... so I think it will work as it is, without any changes. If it don't, just leave a comment, and I'll revise it.

```
public class CustomMarshalerType : ICustomMarshaler
{
    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        return (ulong)Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pNativeData).ToInt64();
    }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
    {
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return IntPtr.Size;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 1 or more size_t parameters on each method... have about 200 I need to expose. This would triple the LOC... I'd probably be better off sticking with UIntPtr...